# Standard of keeping "reference variables" in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a molecule viewer for my AP Chemistry class. I'm assigning each element a different color. For example, hydrogen is white, carbon is black, and oxygen is red.

When I call a new element to be rendered it looks like this:

```
newAtom(x, y, z, color);
```

The atom is then rendered.

Because there's over a hundred elements, there's a lot of different colors.

Should I make s separate class for all these colors? For example:

```
public class AtomColors {

    // By atomic number
    public final static Color H = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    public final static Color He = new Color(1, 0.5f, 1, 1);
    public final static Color Li = new Color(0.5f, 1, 1, 1);
    public final static Color Be = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.5f);
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a standard way or doing this, and which way is the most efficient. That's my question. This there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered a Map<String,Color> with the String representation of the chemical symbol as key, and the associated color as value? That may simplify using the colors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) will fit the best here. Enum is used for representing related constants in language provided structure.

You can represent colours like below:

```
public enum ColorEnum {
    H(1, 1, 1, 1),
    He(1, 0.5f, 1, 1),
    Li(0.5f, 1, 1, 1),
    Be(1, 1, 1, 0.5f);

    private final float cyan;
    private final float magenta;
    private final float yellow;
    private final float black;

    EnumTest(float cyan, float megenta, float yellow, float black) {
        this.cyan = cyan;
        this.megenta = megenta;
        this.yellow = yellow;
        this.black = black;
    }

    public float getCyan() { return cyan; }
    public float getMegenta() { return megenta; }
    public float getYellow() { return yellow; }
    public float getBlack() { return black; }

    public Color getColor() {
            new Color(cyan, megenta, yellow, black);
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
newAtom(x, y, z, ColorEnum.He);
```

I would suggest, to get more information on this topic refer

- Enum Types - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html
- [Effective Java - Chapter 6. Enums and Annotations](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021)

Comment: this is the most correct idiom for Java ( and any other OO language that has `Enum` as a `Class` support.

Comment: It's asking me to apply the Color attribute. This is because it's supposed to be like new Color(ColorEnum.He);

Comment: What do you mean by getters?

Comment: @Chance I am not sure what you are asking. Enum types are by nature singleton, guaranteed by language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). And to use the Enum constants `new` keyword is not required. Another silly guess is, did you changed the newAtom signature to use ColorEnum. `public void newAtom(int x, int y, int z, ColorEnum color)`

Comment: It says: The method createDiffuse(Color) in the type ColorAttribute is not applicable for the arguments (ColorEnum)

Comment: Please go over the link that I have provided. Color and ColorEnum are two different types, so where ever you want to use ColorEnum you have to use that type.

Comment: Jaydeep, I think it would be good to add a member field `color` to the enum.  In the enum's constructor, set it: `this.color = new Color(cyan, magenta, yellow, black);`.  Then add a `getColor()` to the enum class.  That way you don't have to keep constructing a Color object over and over off of the primitive values stored in the enum.

Comment: @MikeClark Yes that may be another option. However, with that, Color should be written as a immutable class.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel Yes.  And [`java.awt.Color` is immutable](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02183/#N1010B).

Comment: @Chance Well, that variation of Color is not immutable. :)  You should not store mutable data in an enum.  Jaydeep is right to point this out.  You might like to write a colorEnumToColor utility method that creates a Color object from a ColorEnum object.

Comment: @MikeClark I was not sure OP is using java.awt.Color or having his own class. Anyway, there are definitely several ways to represent this in different ways.

Comment: How should I do it then?

Comment: Well, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color does not have CMYK constructor, which is the color model Jaydeep's example uses.  So instead of cyan, magenta, yellow, black, you should store red, green, blue, and alpha in the enum.  That would be a good start.

Comment: I have updated the answer with `getColor` method. @Chance you can take this the code as suggestion change as per Mike Clark suggested

Comment: Use RGBA model: `public enum ColorEnum { H(1, 1, 1, 1), He(1, 0.5f, 1, 1), Li(0.5f, 1, 1, 1), Be(1, 1, 1, 0.5f); private final float red; private final float green; private final float blue; private final float alpha; private ColorEnum(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) { this.red = red; this.green = green; this.blue = blue; this.alpha = alpha; } public com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color getColor() { return new com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color(red, green, blue, alpha); } }`.  Now you can use **ColorEnum.He.getColor()** in your program.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is fine.  Using enums is fine.  However, if you want to let your users reconfigure the colors, that will be made difficult by the fact that your variables are final.  Also, if you want to let users reconfigure the colors, you should not store the colors in an enum, because enums should be immutable as a best practice.  Here is what the code might look like if you wanted to let users override your default coloring scheme somehow.

```
public enum Element
{
    Ac("Actinium", 89),
    Ag("Silver", 47),
    Al("Aluminum", 13); 
    // etcetera

    private final String americanEnglishName;
    private final int atomicNumber;

    private Element(String americanEnglishName, int atomicNumber)
    {
        this.americanEnglishName = americanEnglishName;
        this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
    }

    public String getAmericanEnglishName()
    {
        return americanEnglishName;
    }

    public int getAtomicNumber()
    {
        return atomicNumber;
    }
}

class ApplicationSettings
{
    private static final Map<Element, Color> DEFAULT_COLORING;
    static
    {
        EnumMap<Element, Color> colorMap = 
            new EnumMap<Element, Color>(Element.class);
        colorMap.put(Element.Ac, new Color(1, 2, 3));
        colorMap.put(Element.Ag, Color.green);
        colorMap.put(Element.Al, Color.blue);
        // etcetera

        DEFAULT_COLORING = Collections.unmodifiableMap(colorMap);
    }

    private Map<Element, Color> _userPreferredColors = DEFAULT_COLORING;

    public Map<Element, Color> getUserPreferredColors()
    {
        return _userPreferredColors;
    }

    public void setUserPreferredColors(Map<Element, Color> userPreferredColors)
    {
        _userPreferredColors = userPreferredColors;
    }
}

class Application
{
    private ApplicationSettings _settings;

    public Application(ApplicationSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    private void run()
    {
        for(Element element : Element.values())
        {
            Color color = _settings.getUserPreferredColors().get(element);
            System.out.println(element.getAmericanEnglishName() + "=" + color);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ApplicationSettings settings = new ApplicationSettings();
        Application app = new Application(settings);
        app.run();
    }    
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a situation in which EnumMap can be used rather than HashMap.

Comment: @scottb One of the reasons I love StackOverflow is that I am always learning new things while trying to teach.  I updated my example to use EnumMap, which I did not know about until now.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming each color has a number associated which you require to pass to the molecule viewer.

You can create a **HashMap** with *element name(or color name)* as *key* and the *value* would be the *color number*.

Comment: Yes! One thing I've learned in Java is to love HashMaps and ArrayLists. As another improvement, consider reading in the Color values from a file and generating the HashMap from there. It'll definitely look a lot better than hundreds of `myHashMap.put()` lines in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that color is a property of an atom in your design. From an object oriented design point of view, I would have each `Atom` class have a `Color` property which stores its color. The `newAtom` method would then take a position and an `Atom` object to draw and it would access the color property of the `Atom` to figure out which color to draw it with.

If you want to guarantee a unique color easily for an atom, I would use the number of protons to generate a color, for example, keeping green and blue values constant and depending on the number of protons generate a different red value (0 to 255).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if there's a standard way or doing this, and which way is the most efficient.

There is no "standard" way, but the way you are doing it should be just fine.

There are no efficiency issues with doing it this way.  (In fact, efficiency is unlikely to be an issue, no matter how you do it.  The performance bottlenecks are likely to be in the 3D geometry and rendering code.)

The only snag is that this approach is (more or less) forcing you denormalize your data structure; i.e. storing colours on atom instances, rather than elements.  @MikeClark's answer addresses this point clearly.  (@JayPatel's answer seems to be try to do this too ... though his modelling has some issues.  Since when was "Helium" a colour??)

> This there a better way of doing this?

One alternative is to populate a `Map<String, Color>` with colours for each named element.  That is potentially more flexible, especially if you want to be able to add new elements and/or change element colours on the fly (i.e. without changing code).

There are probably others too.

---

My advice is not to "over think" this.  Just implement it in a way that seems natural to you, and if your code starts to get awkward / repetitive / messy as a result of some "less than optimal" data structure design decisions ... revisit the decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a list of constants that are known to you at compile time (such as the elements in the periodic table), this is a the right time to use an enum.  Enums are instance-controlled for you and are type-safe right out of the box.  And as your needs grow, you have the flexibility to add enum methods or even constant-specific methods.

Moreover, there are already optimized collection classes that simplify working with collections of Enum constants: EnumSet (for sets of enums that could, say, represent a combination of colors), and EnumMap for working with collections of data mapped to particular enum constants.